# What is the name of the 2 rakaat salat that we offer before fajr?

Tags: salat, sunnah

As salaam mu alaikum.

What is the name of the 2 rakaat salat that we offer before fajr? It is said that it is the most beneficial.

Please help. I have been reading this salat as 2 nafil, but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

JazakaAllah khair

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q &A site about Islam. For further information about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Fajr is a time which ends with the dawn and it refers to the Sunnah prayer which should be performed before the corresponding fard and most maddhabs call the fard prayer by the same name while both some ahadith and the Maliki madhhab uses a different term "Sobh" (morning).

Comment: This salaah is before the 2Sunnah & 2fardh of Fajr

Comment: I am not sure about the question but for Farj there is 2 Rakaat salah that is fard, plus 2 Rakaat sunnah that should be performed before the fard, that is all.
worth noticing that there is no salah after perfoming the fard.

What people normaly do is, pray 2 rakaat silently as sunnah, then wait for Adthan of the fajr to pray the 2 rakaat fard.

Comment: Well your question is totally ambiguous because you didn't mention, when this prayer should be performed...

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaykum,

Your question is quite vague so there are two potential answers

**1. The 2 immediately before the 2 farz of fajr**

This is the 2 sunnah rakaats of fajr and is mentioned to be the most important of all sunnah (The prophet(S.A.W) himself said this)

**2. The 2 in the third part of the night before subha sadiq(start of fajr)**

These 2 rakaats are the nafl of tahajjud which is the most important nafl salaah. This is also very beneficial and has very high rewards.

Allah knows best.

Comment: Do you have any backup for the second prayer?

Comment: There are lost of hadith citing tahajjud as a very important prayer with various rewards. I may edit this later

Comment: I see from my understanding tahhajjud is off-topic here. Because once fajr started the time for tahajjud has ended.

Comment: Ik but the question does not specifically say how long before fajr so i put both answers in case

Answer (score 0):

***(16)Chapter: Between every two calls (Adhan and Iqama) there is a Salat (prayer) (that is optional) for the one who wants to offer it.***

Narrated `Abdullah bin Mughaffal:

The prophet said, "There is a prayer between the two Adhans (Adhan and Iqama), there is a prayer between the two Adhans." And then while saying it the third time he added, "For the one who wants to (pray)."
*(Sahih al-Bukhari 627)*

Another Hadith:
"Once I passed the night in the house of my aunt Maimuna. Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) offered the `Isha' prayer and then came to the house and offered four rak`at an slept. Later on, he woke up and stood for the prayer and I stood on his left side. He drew me to his right and prayed five rak`at (Tahajud) and then two(Fajar Sunnah). He then slept till I heard him snoring (or heard his breath sounds). Afterwards he went out for the morning prayer".
*(Sahih al-Bukhari 697)*